# How do I copy the last row made by a form response to the last row of another sheet automatically on form submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find a solution for the following problem:
Everytime someone answers to my Form a new row is created in the google sheet called „formresponses“. Then I got another sheet inside the same file where I copy these new rows to.
currently I am using the code below that runs the function after clicking on a button where this function is assigned to.

But I know I know that there is something called Trigger which fires the function automatically after a new Form is submitted. Unfortunately im new to coding and don’t really know how to use it. I tried searching the internet but I did not find out how to use it in my case.

So the actual copy function which basically works fine is

```
function copy(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
  var formsheet = ss.getSheetByName("formresponses");
  var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName("targetsheet");
  
  var numOfCol = formsheet.getLastColumn(); // Last Column Indexnumber
  
  var lastrowForm = formsheet.getLastRow();
  var lastrowTarget = targetsheet.getLastRow(); 
  var targetrow = lastrowTarget + 1;       // Lastrow() always gives the last row that contains content, so to get the next empty row we simply add +1 
  
  var rangetoCopy = formsheet.getRange(lastrowForm,1,1,numOfCol).getValues();

  targetsheet.getRange(targetrow,1,1,numOfCol).setValues(rangetoCopy);  
  
}
```

how can I make this work automatically everytime a new form answer is submitted ? I would really appreciate your help guys! :)

Comment: Why don't you simply reference to the response sheet by formula?

Answer (score 0):

In case multiple submits come at the same time,
you may not get the expected row correctly with `getLastRow`

You need an `on form submit` trigger

The event passed to such trigger include all the answers, so just append it to the target sheet

```js
function formSubmit(e) {
  const id = 'ID of Spreadsheet';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const targetsheet = getSheetByName('targetsheet');
  targetsheet.appendRow(e.values);
}
```

References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)
- [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) (create a `form submit` trigger with the above function)

Comment: Hi idfurw, thanks for the fast answer. Sorry for that dumb question but since I am a newbie I dont really know what to do exactly right now ? Shall I just delete my code and use urs instead or add ur code to my code ? Where in ur code the sheet with the form responses is declared ? Pls can u lead me step by step ? 

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, it shoule be `e.values`. You could simply use my code (don't forget to put `id` and `sheetName`!) See more at [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)